# Proof of ring isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Proof that $Z[X]/(X^2-22) ≈ Z[\sqrt{22}]$.

I have tried all sorts of things to resolve this but I don't know how to wrap my head around it.
Can you please explain how to solve these kind of equations? Thank you.

Comment: well, you have to prove there's an isomorphism.. Why don't you try to write down the first function you can think and prove that it's an isomorphism?

Answer (score 5):

You need to define a ring homomorphism
$$
\phi:\Bbb Z[X]\longrightarrow\Bbb Z[\sqrt{22}]
$$
with the property that $\phi(1)=1$ and $\phi(X)=\sqrt{22}$.

Now (HINTS):

- show that there is a (in fact unique) ring homomorphism as such;
- show that $\phi$ is surjective;
- show that $\ker\phi=(X^2-22)$
- conclude.

Comment: The first hint doesn't make much sense. $\phi$ is constructed as a ring homomorphism, using the universal property of the polynomial ring; so you don't have to calculate anything. If you don't want to use the universal property for some reason, then "Define a ring homomorphism by $\phi(X)=\sqrt{22}$" is not a definition.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: yeah, right, I somehow rushed in my answer: I edited it slightly changing the wording. Should be fine now

Comment: For "show that there is a (in fact unique) ring homomorphism as such",
do I need to pick a random equation from $ϕ$ to check ?

Comment: @CioroianuDenis: well, $\Bbb Z[X]$ is generated *as a ring* by $1$ and $X$. So, for any other ring $R$, you can define a ring homomorphism $\phi:\Bbb Z[X]\rightarrow R$ just by declaring who $\phi(1)$ and $\phi(X)$ are. Indeed you then have $\phi\left(\sum_{k=0}^dz_kX^k\right)=\sum_{k=0}^dz_k\phi(1)\phi(X)^k$. Moreover, there's no problem setting $\phi(1)$ and $\phi(X)$ at will, since $1$ and $X$ are algebraically independent in $\Bbb Z[X]$ (i.e. satisfy no algebraic relation among them). The uniqueness of $\phi$ follows immediately from the construction but it is not needed for your problem.

Comment: @AdLibitum: $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is generated by $X$. The unit is contained in any subring (by definition of ring; since we don't talk about rngs here). $1,X$ are algebraically dependent.

Comment: So we apply the isomorphism theorem which says(in our case) that $Z[X]/ker ϕ ≈ Z[\sqrt{22}]$ ? And then what?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: also the ring $(2\Bbb Z)[X]$ is generated just by $X$?

Comment: @CioroianuDenis: Then, that is exactly what you wanted in the first place, once you realize that $\ker\phi$ is as in my answer.

Comment: @AdLibitum: This is not a ring. It is a rng.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: rng doesn't ring a bell :) Or you mean to say a ring without 1? But that would be a r1ng without 1, methinks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

The evaluation homomorphism: define

$$\phi:\Bbb Z[x]\to\Bbb Z[\sqrt{22}]\;,\;\;\phi(f(x)):=f\left(\sqrt{22}\right)$$

Show this indeed is a ring homomorphism, which is trivially surjective. Now, what about its kernel?

$$f\in\ker\phi\implies f(\sqrt{22})=0$$

Yet $\;x^2-22\;$ is **the minimal** polynomial of the complex number (or if you prefer: the algebraic) $\;\sqrt{22}\;$ over $\;\Bbb Z\;$ (or over $\;\Bbb Q\;$ , if you prefer), so...

Comment: I don't understand this $ϕ(f(x)):=f(\sqrt{22})$, who is $f(x)$ ?

Comment: @CioroianuDenis Where am I defining $\;\phi\;$ on? Integer polynomials!

Answer (score 0):

Define $\Phi : \mathbb{Z}[X] \to \mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{22} ] .$  $\Phi (W) =W(\sqrt{22} )$ then from the first isomorphism theorem we have that $$\mathbb{Z}[X] /_{\mbox{Ker} \Phi } \approx  \mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{22} ]$$ but $$\mbox{Ker} \Phi =\mathbb{Z}[X]/_{(X^2 -22 )}$$